# how to enable ws-addressing and how to pass generatedmessegeId while posting xml data to web service in javaclient with httpclient

Tags: spring-boot, soap, http-post, httpclient

how to enable ws-addressing and how to pass generatedmessegeId while posting xml data to web service in javaclient with httpclient solution

i am facing 500 internal server error

configuration is below

```java
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(loginId, pass);
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
                    NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> reg = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create()
                    .register("https", socketFactory).build();
HttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(reg);
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(cm)
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
            
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
```